# ggsave error "cannot open file"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am running `ggsave('plot.pdf')` and get this error:

```
Error in grDevices::pdf(..., version = version) :
  cannot open file 'plot.pdf'
```

Even when I don't have plot.pdf open.  I am working on a NFS. If I ggsave to a new file, and then run ggsave again to the same path, it will overwrite the file successfully.  However, if I open and close the file before running ggsave to the same path, I get the above error.  Any thoughts on why this would be happening?

Comment: Are you sure you closed the file? Adobe Reader isn't open somewhere holding a lock to the file? And it isn't previewed in the file explorer?

Comment: Yes, Adobe Reader is closed and it is not previewed in the file explorer and I still get the error.

Comment: There are also no hidden dotfiles in the directory containing plot.pdf

Comment: So you are on a linux box connecting to an NFS store?

Comment: Yes, I'm ssh'd to a linux box that is connecting to a NFS.

Comment: Something similar just happened to me now: my script saves pdf plots to a specific directory on my local machine, but that directory is not tracked in GitHub. When I cloned my code on the remote machine and tried to run it there, I got this error because on that machine the directory where the pictures were supposed to go was absent. I had to mkdir it first.