# R error saving ggplot pdf

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2

When I try to save a plot made using ggplot as a pdf using this code:

```
library(ggplot2)

file = "/data/mda/20150630-1Mb-full_comparison-low_depth_hTERT/result/comparison_figure/SD_rank_custom.csv"
figure_file = "/data/mda/20150604-1Mb-full_comparison-low_depth_hTERT/result/comparison_figure/SD_rank_custom.pdf"

sd_data <- as.data.frame(read.csv(file, header=TRUE))

# generate box plot
ggplot(
    data=sd_data,
    aes(
        x=Experiment, 
        y=SD
    )
)+  
theme_bw() + #use bw theme
geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) + #hide outlier points
geom_jitter() + 
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))   

ggsave(
  filename=figure_file,
  width=10,
  height=10
)
```

I get the following error:

> Error in grDevices::pdf(..., version = version) :
>
> cannot open file 'file.pdf'
>
> Calls: ggsave -> device ->
>
> Execution halted

I think my version of R was recently updated to 3.2.0, and I've confirmed that it works fine in v3.1.1 so I'm assuming this is version related.  I also confirmed I can write a csv file to the directory.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Could you please post the code that you are using?

Comment: Do you have write access to your current working directory? What does `getwd()` return?

Comment: above 2 comments answered in post

Comment: Does `file.info("/data/mda/20150604-1Mb-full_comparison-low_depth_hTERT/result/comparison_figure/")$isdir` return `TRUE`? It really just seems like a file permissions problem. Reading is different from writing. Can you write to that directory?

Comment: Do you have the pdf open?

Comment: had the same issue, renamed the file and it got fixed

Answer (score 3):

I think you're trying to write to a non-existent folder, and as far as I know grDevices won't allow this. [Someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24191231/ggsave-error-cannot-open-file) seems to have a similar issue.

I tried your code both in R 3.1.1 and 3.2.1—they both give the same error (unless the directory is created on beforehand.

You could try adding the following line of code:

```
dir.create(file.path(dirname(figure_file)))
```

It will create the directory for you.

Comment: the directory definitely exists and I am able to write .csv files to it, but not pdfs for some reason.  No, the pdf is not open.  I just heard from our sys admin that there is some weird problem with my write permissions, so waiting on that.  Thanks for your responses

Answer (score 3):

I had the same, turned out I had already an object with the same name saved in that directory that apparently does not get overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

I just got this error while running a for loop to create many pdf files containing charts.

For me, the error was resolved when I simply closed out of the one pdf file I opened earlier to examine my output. R was throwing the error because I had the file open, so it could not overwrite it. It is another plausible cause for this error.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when my file name was too long - and therefore the path name in windows exceeded the allowed letters limit. Shortening the file name solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons for `Error in grDevices::pdf` is write permissions. Proper write permissions should solve the issue. - `chmod 777 -R dirname`

Answer (score 0):

T faced the same issue and found out that the here() is not pointing to the correct directory in which the R script file is. Solution to this is, either try to point the here() to the correct directory or close\quit the R studio and open the script directly in R studio i.e. Open the R studio fresh then, here() will automatically point to the same directory as to that of the script.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I fixed it by moving the working directory, since it thought it was in system32.

If you are working in Rstudio

- Session
- Set working directory
- Desktop

and either make a new folder or choose an existing one